# How to show image in webview?

Tags: iphone, image, uiwebview, base64, xcode4.5

I am trying to show image in UIWebView.But I don't know why my image is not shown in UIWebVeiw. Here is my code.

```
-(void)pInterest
{
UIImage *myImage;
myImage=imgView.image;
WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
webViewController.mypimage = myImage;
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Now after passing image to WebViewController my WebViewController code is,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mypimage, 1.0f);
[Base64 initialize];
NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];
 NSMutableString *htmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<html> <body>"];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<p align=\"center\"><a href=%@ class=\"pin-it-button\" count-layout=\"horizontal\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png\" title=\"Pin It\" /></a></p>", buttonUrl];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<p align=\"center\"><img width=\"400px\" height = \"400px\" src=%@></img></p>", imageUrl];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js\"></script>"];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"</body> </html>"];
[mywebview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[mywebview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
[mywebview setOpaque:NO];
}
```

when I tried with this code it show below result.

[image]

Any help will be appriated.Thanks

Comment: you want to implement pinterest in your project?

Comment: yes @Sudha i want to post image on pinterest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
       - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  [imagePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

   image= [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    savedImagePath = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"savedImagePath..%@",savedImagePath);

    // imageView is my image from camera
    imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];



}

    - (NSString*) generatePinterestHTML {


     NSString *description = @"Post your description here";

    NSString *stringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",savedImagePath];
    NSLog(@"stringUrl:%@", stringUrl);
//    
   NSURL *urlToUpload = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:stringUrl];

   sUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",urlToUpload];

 // sUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-w4oTZjlpgwo/T5_pi-KJPuI/AAAAAAAAAoM/rKm3E0XCbgY/s1600/red_rose_flower3.jpg"];
    NSLog(@"URL:%@", sUrl);
    NSString *protectedUrl = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(__bridge CFStringRef)sUrl, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));
    NSLog(@"Protected URL:%@", protectedUrl);
    NSString *imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", sUrl];
    NSString *buttonUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=www.flor.com&media=%@&description=%@\"", protectedUrl, description];

    NSMutableString *htmlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<html> <body>"];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<p align=\"center\"><a href=%@ class=\"pin-it-button\" count-layout=\"horizontal\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png\" title=\"Pin It\" /></a></p>", buttonUrl];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<p align=\"center\"><img width=\"400px\" height = \"400px\" src=%@></img></p>", imageUrl];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js\"></script>"];
    [htmlString appendFormat:@"</body> </html>"];
    return htmlString;
}

- (void) postToPinterest {
    NSString *htmlString = [self generatePinterestHTML];
    NSLog(@"Generated HTML String:%@", htmlString);
    webViewPinterest.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    webViewPinterest.opaque = NO;
    if ([webViewPinterest isHidden]) {
        [webViewPinterest setHidden:NO];
    }
    [webViewPinterest loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    //[webViewPinterest loadHTMLString:@"<img src=images.png>" baseURL:nil];
}
```

And if you want to upload local image then first convert your imagePath into url and then try this but write your code of converting url where i put comments and then pass that url...... Hope it will helpful for you......

Comment: let me check beacuse for this method i need to use delegate method to call generatePinterestHTML beacuse i catch image from mainclasss to WebViewController and then from WebViewController i am posting image on pinterest.

Comment: i think this method will solved my problem.but still there is some confusion ,how i can pass my mypimage instance in this url.please looks my above code and suggest any solution.

Comment: NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mypimage, 1.0f);
    [Base64 initialize];
    NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];
        NSString *stringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strEncoded];
        NSLog(@"stringUrl:%@", stringUrl);
      NSURL *urlToUpload = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:stringUrl];
    NSString *sUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",urlToUpload]; i tried with these lines but still webview is blank.but when i use your code it show flower image there.

Comment: my saved image path is this savedImagePath = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"savedImagePath..%@",savedImagePath); NSString *stringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",savedImagePath];
    NSLog(@"stringUrl:%@", stringUrl);
//    
   NSURL *urlToUpload = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:stringUrl];
   
   sUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",urlToUpload];
    
    // imageView is my image from camera
    imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];

Comment: I choose my image from photo gallery of simulator

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24121/discussion-between-bob-apple-and-sudha)