# How to align UIWebView contents in Pinterest integration

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, pinterest

My app has a feature Pinterest sharing for this purpose I have followed [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749839/how-to-show-image-in-webview?rq=1) it is working good but when i am sharing the `UIWebView` contents are looking nonaligned. attached is the sample screenshot

[image]

But I have gone through shop style app which has aligned contents in `UIWebView` attached is sample image

[image]

How can I get the `UIWebView` contents like shop style app? Please guide me

Comment: You need to set alignment or image pixel size in html code of uiwebview

Comment: Can u paste some code where u looking for changes?

Comment: mind sharing some code ?? and url you are passing to UIWebview.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling autolayout feature and set your own constraints for the UI items. For more reference Check on the [this](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/18/autolayout-in-interface-builder/) link. I followed the same tutorial for my app and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your, I don't think this should be the answer for this. Because I suppose to adjust the layout of UIWebView's body content

Answer (score 0):

After reading the related answer, I think the problem might come from the hard coded HTML code you generate in `-(NSString*)generatePinterestHTML` function. According to your screenshots, your sharing form is *staying* next to your image, while it should go to a new paragraph. Though in the related answer's code, @Sudha is putting `<p>` tags for line breaks, whether you've omitted them, or you've just forgotten them.

In the first case, you should insert a `<br />` tag at the beginning of the third `[htmlString appendFormat];` instruction.

Which means you should end up with this snippet:

```
...

[htmlString appendFormat:@"<html> <body>"];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<p align=\"center\"><a href=%@ class=\"pin-it-button\" count-layout=\"horizontal\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png\" title=\"Pin It\" /></a></p>", buttonUrl];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<br/><p align=\"center\"><img width=\"400px\" height = \"400px\" src=%@></img></p>", imageUrl];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js\"></script>"];
[htmlString appendFormat:@"</body> </html>"];
...
```

**Note : *If this answer didn't help you, you should post the code you used, so that we can directly see what's wrong***